# Obtain location of maximum inside a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, max, dimension

How can I get a maximum of a three-dimensional matrix (which was previously two-dimensional and converted to a three-dimensional matrix by `reshape`) in MATLAB so that I can then get the position of that maximum value in the matrix?

I wrote the following code, but unfortunately the dimensions obtained for the maximum values are larger than the dimensions of the matrix.

```
mxshirin=max(max(frvrdin))

[X,Y,Z]=size(frvrdin)
[o,i]=find(frvrdin==mxshirin)
xo=size(o)
xi=size(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `frvrdin` is 3D, `max(max(frvrdin))` will be a 1x1x3 vector:

```
frvrdin = rand(3,3,3);
max(max(frvrdin))
ans(:,:,1) =
    0.8235
ans(:,:,2) =
    0.9502
ans(:,:,3) =
    0.7547
```

Don't nest `max()` functions, simply use the `'all'` switch to take the max of the **entire** matrix at once.

```
max(frvrdin,[],'all')
ans =
    0.9340
```

If you're on an older MATLAB, use column flattening: `max(frvrdin(:))`.

You can't use the automated location output of `max` `[val,idx]=max()` on more than two dimensions, so use `find` and [`ind2sub`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html):

```
frvrdin = rand(3,3,3);
val = max(frvrdin,[],'all');  % Find maximum over all dims
idx = find(abs(frvrdin-val)<1e-10); % Compare within tolerance
[row,col,page] = ind2sub(size(frvrdin),idx);  % Get subscript indices
```

where `row` is the index into your first dimension, `col` into the second and finally `page` into the third.

Comment: Thank you.
Your code works fine. But I want to specify the maximum value in each dimension of my 3D matrix, and then be able to extract the position of the maximum value correctly. The code I wrote does not calculate the positions correctly. Unless I insert a two-dimensional matrix into the code every time I want to estimate the third dimension, this will require writing a loop that may not work properly and also increase the size of the code.
Please help me if you can      @Adriaan

Comment: @shirin that's a rather different question that what you initially asked. Also what do you mean by "maximum value in each dimension"? Inputting a dimensional argument into `max(A,2)` will still output a 2D matrix in this case.

Comment: Excuse me, I mean of each dimension is the third dimension..Thank you for your help.
I realized my problems @Adriaan